# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception (flutter build apk)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\wasiq\Downloads\flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\wasiq\Downloads\flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11m 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     664.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: Putting the entire log here will be helpful. Currently, this data is insufficient to answer the question.